# how to check a field is char or number?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a NVARCHAR field in my table. (using Oracle 11g)

I want check it has char data or number data.

help me to write a select query. (using PL-SQL)

I think I can write it with case, but I can't implement that. (I have no method for checking isChar and isNumber)

```
select
       case <myField>
           when <isChar> then
               <this is a char data>
           when <IsNum> then
               <this is number data>
       End
from <myTable>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `REGEXP_LIKE`

```
SELECT t.*,
       CASE 
         WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(column1, '^[0-9]+$') THEN 'Numeric' 
         ELSE 'Char' 
       END data_type 
  FROM table1 t;
```

And without it

```
SELECT t.*,
       CASE 
         WHEN LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE (column1, '0123456789',' ')))  IS NULL THEN 'Numeric' 
         ELSE 'Char' 
       END data_type 
  FROM table1 t;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f6ecb/13)** demo

*Both versions can be adjusted to accommodate period, plus and minus signs if needed*

**UPDATE** As @tbone correctly commented these queries don't take into account `NULL`s and return 'Char' and 'Numeric' as data_type respectively when a value of column1 is `NULL`.

There are at least two options how to deal with it:

**First** Simply filter out rows with `NULL` values if we are not interested in them

```
...
WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL
```

**Second** Introduce `NULL` (obviously it can be 'N/A' or something else) data type in `CASE`

```
SELECT t.*,
       CASE 
       WHEN column1 IS NULL THEN NULL
       ELSE CASE 
         WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(column1, '^[0-9]+$') THEN 'Numeric' 
         ELSE 'Char'
         END
       END data_type 
  FROM table1 t
```

Here is updated **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/157a1/14)** demo

Comment: you might need to check for NULLs as well.  I believe your code will show nulls as 'Char'.  The possible output should be 'Numeric', 'Char', or 'Null'

Comment: @tbone Thanks. Fair enough. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this SQL. I have assumed in case statement there is character data.

```
 select case <myField>
        when (ascii(char)>=65 and ascii(char)<=90) OR (ascii(char)>=97 and ascii(char)<=122)  
        then
                   <this is a char data>
        when ascii(char)>=48 and ascii(char)<=57 
        then
                   <this is number data>
        End
 from <myTable>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it's not force to write with switch-case structure! if you can write with your suggestion structure , write that...

Comment: The ASCII() function only returns a result for the first character in a string so this won't work for longer strings.

Comment: @Ben : agreed. i assumed he was writing sql for a single charater.